$\forall x\in\{\} : \exists y\in\mathbb N : x<y$ true or false?
We are simply asked if this statement is true or false. From what I was able to gather this statement is true because an empty set has no values to make a counter argument.
Yet I do not fully understand the logic behind this specific statement so I'd be really glad if someone could explain it in more detail.

$\forall x\in{} (P(x))$ is true for any statement $P(x).$ Basically, because if $x\in{},$ we have a contradiction.

There's not much more detail than what you said. If it's not true that for all $x$ in the empty set, $P(x)$, then there must be some $x$ in the empty set for which $\neg P(x)$.  But even without the "$\neg P(x)$", we know that's not possible.

@TobySaunders-A'Court Why do there need to be values to make a statement true?

Because the negation of "for all" is "there exists," which can't hold with no values.

Your interpretation is false. $\forall x\in A: P(x)$ is actually not a valid first order logic statement, but rather a shorthand for $\forall x:(x\in A\implies P(x)).$

I think the question's wrong.

But also, $\forall x\in A: P(x)$ and $\forall x\in B: Q(x)$ lets us deduce $\forall x\in A\cap B: P(x)\land Q(x),$ while your interpretation would require an extra condition, $A\cap B\neq \emptyset.$

See also Vacuous Truth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Indeed, and it is also possible for a statement to be vacuously false. Like, "All of the people who live on Mars are Spanish".

@K.defaoite: That statement is also vacuously true.  It's not false (vacuously or otherwise).

If Martians are nonexistent, then "every Martian is Spanish" is true. Simiarly, if $x$ isn't a member of $S,$ then every $x$ in $S$ does satisfy $P(x),$ that is, ∀x∈S P(x) is true.

See Range of quantification as well as Guarded quantifier: the abbreviated syntax $\forall x \in A(Px)$ is more formally: $\forall x (x \in A \to Px)$ and still betetr avoiding setmembership relation and using instead a predicate: $\forall x (Ax \to Px)$.
